# How to make PhpStorm listen for xDebug connections with an "idekey" defined in php.ini

Tags: php, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I've set up PhpStorm with Vagrant and xDebug following this fine tutorial:

[How to integrate PhpStrom, xDebug and Vagrant](https://danemacmillan.com/how-to-configure-xdebug-in-phpstorm-through-vagrant/#content-listen-connections)

I know there are many people who successfully set up xDebug following the instruction. However, the problem that I cannot overcome is the following:

Each time I start a debug session (pressing "Debug") on a project, PhpStorm starts listening for connection with random, numeric 'idekey', e.g:

> Waiting for incoming connection with ide key '15927'

The ide key being listened to is different each time a session is started.

I've set up my `php.ini` with `xdebug.idekey="vagrant"`. I'm also using [xdebug helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?hl=en) to trigger a session in the browser which sets a cookie with `idekey="vagrant"`.

I'd expect then PhpStorm to listen to connections with ide key "vagrant". Why does it keep assigning random, numeric ide keys on session start? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I'd say "do not worry about that" -- IDE can accept connections with any key. I'm not using keys at all (from PhpStorm side) .. and it works. Just activate "phone handle" icon for IDE to start listening for connections. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm (I'm using zero-config approach)

Comment: @LazyOne I might be wrong but the zero-config approach seems not to work when developing with Vagrant where remore xDebug connection has to be set up

Comment: You are wrong on this one. It's all about xdebug configuration, possible path mappings (to match local to remote) + possible your firewall (be it local or remote one). Just have a look at "Related" column on the right side -- in most cases it's "i forgot to configure this" or "I've configured this when I should not have" etc.

Comment: You should provide: 1) your xdebug config (e.g. xdebug porting of `phpinfo()` output) 2) xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug attempt -- http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log (does xdebug tries to connect to correct ip:port? does it tries to connect at all (which means -- you are actually not doing any debugging) 3) If it tires but PhpStorm is unable to detect it -- then it can be investigated further.

Comment: @LazyOne I will try zer-config apprach, thanks for suggesting this one. Howver, I'd like to first diagnose the problem I have with the current config as I'm convinced it should really work. I've set up a new thread where I give some more details about some strange PhpStorm's behaviour http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31165852/phpstorm-xdebug-mappings-either-not-found-or-ide-not-listening